# mstest - unit test running duration

Tags: unit-testing, structuremap, mstest, automapper

In our project so far we have 621 unit tests. executing these tests lasts ~35 seconds. these are typical unit tests, which should not deal with network or disk operations. I think the most costly operations should come with reflection (coming via StructureMap and AutoMapper).

So:

1 - Does it smell bad to execute 621 unit tests in 35 seconds using MSTest?

2 - Would it be faster if these were nunit tests?

3 - What are your benchmarks, if you have any? Should we look into, if there is some unwanted code running in tests?

Comment: I'd say you should profile the test using a profiler and actually see what parts of the code are slow or that are called frequently. Then apply Jimmy's advice if the problem is with bootstrapping the frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

One quick thing to check is to see if expensive initialization operations are happening once per AppDomain, or once per test, or once per test fixture. We sped up our tests quite a bit by making sure that StructureMap, AutoMapper, NHibernate and others were only initialized once for ALL unit tests executed.